# how resetZoom() en multiple charts (ng2charts or chartjs)?

Tags: angular, chart.js, ng2-charts, chartjs-plugin-zoom

i have a page with multiple charts and i add the pluggin for zoom.

i reset the zoom making

`this.chart.chart['resetZoom']();`

and it work... in only 1 chart, just the first one.

if i make xonsole.log to this.chart, the element get only the firts chart.
also, if i made this.chart.update() it work with all the charts

```
@ViewChild(BaseChartDirective, {static: true }) chart: BaseChartDirective;
```

that its the way that i access to the chart functions

i can't post the code becaouse its tooooooooo long xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to assign created chart to a property in your class, and after that to call .reset(). Check this example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z838vk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)